# iMacros. How can I click a link in with tag <a>?

Tags: imacros

iMacros. How can I click a link in with tag ?

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="xxxxxx" style="margin:0;padding:14px 24px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#FFF;background-color:#13d883;font-size:14px;font-weight:600;margin-right:10px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;" target="_blank">Activate your trial</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

imacros works well with XPATH, so you can use it to target specific element:

```
TAG XPATH="./a[contains(@href,'xxxxxx')]"
```

or

```
TAG XPATH="./a[contains(.,'Activate your trial')]"
```

CSS selectors work well too, the sample of syntax to use them is similar:

```
TAG SELECTOR="[selector_expression]"
```

more useful info on how to use TAG command here:
http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG

Another option to implement mouse click itself is the "EVENT" command (for some specific sites this can be the only way to click elements):

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK XPATH="./a[contains(.,'Activate your trial')]" BUTTON=0
```

more info here: http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT

Answer (score 0):

Is your question just how to click that link?

You can use the iMacros recording functionality to generate simple code: http://wiki.imacros.net/First_Steps#Recording_Macros

Just click the link manually while recoding and you're good. You can then replay the recorded macro whenever you wish.

---

It will give you something like this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Activate<SP>your<SP>trial
```